How detect was clicked Win+Shift+S (made scren) JavaScript
How can I determine that the combination "Win +Shift+ S" was pressed?
I'm trying to do so, but the screenshot window comes out faster. Does anyone know how to fix this?
KeyCode for:
Win - 91
Shift - 16
S - 83

We can't use shiftKey and metaKey because they only fire when we release them last
Here is my code:
<script>
    const set = new Set();

    window.addEventListener('keydown', event => {
        set.add(event.keyCode)
        console.log(set)
    });

    window.addEventListener('keyup', event => {
        if (set.has(91) && set.has(16) && set.has(83)) {
            alert('made screen')
        }
        set.delete(event.keyCode);
        console.log(set)
    });
</script>


I don't have much hope that this can be done in any reliable way. The short cut on "OS level" will always take precedence over your JS code. So I would assume that you never see the "S" button being pressed because that opens the snipping tool without the event reaching your JS code

It looks like you are not so much about detecting Win+Shift+S specifically, but about preventing the user from taking a screen shot of your web page.

you cant prevent users from doing this, they can simply use a phone to take a screenshot. any data that the client receives can be saved and copied, so don't do this.

Seems your intention is to hide website content with warning when screenshot is used,
I am unable to make it up to [win-shift-s], but managed with [win-shift], moreover even if one was able to,it wouldn't be before screenshot tool pops up,
So I guess you would be okay with detecting at win-shift itself (the below code will support you,showing alert before screenshot occurs)


var shortcut = {
  // (A) SET SHORTCUT KEYS TO LISTEN TO
  listen : null,
  set : (listen) => {
    // (A1) KEY SEQUENCE + FUNCTION TO RUN
    shortcut.listen = listen;

    // (A2) KEY PRESS LISTENERS
    window.addEventListener("keydown", (evt) => {
      shortcut.track(evt.key.toLowerCase(), true);
    });
    window.addEventListener("keyup", (evt) => {
      shortcut.track(evt.key.toLowerCase(), false);
    });
  },

  // (B) KEY PRESS SEQUENCE TRACKER
  sequence : [],
  track : (key, direction) => {
    // (B1) PREVENT AUTO CLEANING
    if (shortcut.junk != null) { clearTimeout(shortcut.junk); }

    // (B2) KEY DOWN
    if (direction) { if (!shortcut.sequence.includes(key)) {
      shortcut.sequence.push(key);
    }}

    // (B3) KEY UP
    else {
      let idx = shortcut.sequence.indexOf(key);
      if (idx != -1) { shortcut.sequence.splice(idx, 1); }
    }

    // (B4) HIT SHORTCUT?
    if (shortcut.sequence.length != 0) {
      let seq = shortcut.sequence.join("-");
      if (shortcut.listen[seq]) {
        shortcut.sequence = [];
        shortcut.listen[seq]();
      }

      // (B5) PREVENT "STUCK SEQUENCE" WHEN USER LEAVES PAGE
      // E.G. OPEN NEW TAB WHILE IN MIDDLE OF KEY PRESS SEQUENCE
      else {
        shortcut.junk = setTimeout(shortcut.clean, 600)
      }
    }
  },

  // (C) AUTO CLEANUP
  junk : null,
  clean : () => {
    shortcut.junk = null;
    shortcut.sequence = [];
  }
};
window.addEventListener("DOMContentLoaded", () => {
  shortcut.set({
    "meta-shift" : () => {// Use https://keycode.info/ to help you get the key name [*]
       document.getElementById("demoA").innerHTML = "Win Shift IS PRESSED"//[*]
       document.getElementById("demoA").style.color = "green";//[*]
       document.getElementById("demoA").style.backgroundColor = "lightgreen";//[*]
      }
  });
});
<!-- FOR THE DEMO -->
<div id="demoA"></div>



After words:

Above code is took from https://stackoverflow.com/a/70797227/14862885
You have to consider that there exists [PrntScn] which is undetectable,user may use any custom screenshot tool,shortcut

